# Bold database dates in MonthCalendar

Tags: mysql, vb.net, monthcalendar

I am trying to make my calendar number bold when there is an event saved into that specific date. I have searched and tried to do it but i cant.

How can i make the date bold when i saved an event into that selected date?

Here's what i tried to do but it cant convert to 1 dimensional array of date.

```
mydbcon = New MySqlConnection
    mydbcon.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;userid=root;password=root;database=database"
    Dim reader As MySqlDataReader
    Dim bold = Form4.MonthCalendar1.SelectionRange.Start.Month
    Try
        mydbcon.Open()
        Dim Query As String
        Query = "Insert into database.calendar (eventname,Date,Time,Description) Values ('" & TextBox2.Text & "','" & Form4.MonthCalendar1.SelectionRange.Start & "','" & ComboBox1.SelectedItem & "','" & TextBox1.Text & "')"
        COMMAND = New MySqlCommand(Query, mydbcon)
        reader = COMMAND.ExecuteReader
        MessageBox.Show("Event Succesfully Saved")

        Form4.MonthCalendar1.BoldedDates = bold
        mydbcon.Close()
    Catch ex As MySqlException
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        mydbcon.Dispose()
    End Try
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding bold date to calendar - example:

```
    MonthCalendar1.AddBoldedDate(CDate("03-12-2015"))
    MonthCalendar1.UpdateBoldedDates()
```

Read dates from database - example:

```
    mydbcon = New MySqlConnection
    mydbcon.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;userid=root;password=root;database=database"
    Dim reader As MySqlDataReader

    Try
        mydbcon.Open()
        Dim Query As New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand
        Dim eventDate As String
        Query.Connection = mydbcon
        Query.CommandText = "SELECT Date FROM database ORDER BY Date"
        reader = Query.ExecuteReader

        If reader.HasRows = True Then
            While reader.Read
                eventDate = reader.GetValue(reader.GetOrdinal("Date")).ToShortDateString
                MonthCalendar1.AddBoldedDate(CDate(eventDate))
            End While
            reader.Close()
            MonthCalendar1.UpdateBoldedDates()
        End If

        mydbcon.Close()
    Catch ex As MySqlException
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        mydbcon.Dispose()
    End Try
```

Comment: Bro. I received Missingmemberexemption please help